# How to get text of a button from another class

Tags: java, android

I have an arraylist of items  and each item contains several button in Main1 class. Let's say i want to take the text of that button from Main class. So how can i do that?

```
public class Main1 extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button button1,button2,button3,button4,button5,button6,button7,button8;

TextView textView;
private String a,b;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);
    button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    button2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    button3=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    button4=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    button5=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
    button6=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn6);
    button7=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn7);
    button8=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn8);
    textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtsua);



    textView.setOnClickListener(this);
}
public String getA() {
    return button1.getText().toString();
}

public String getB() {
    return button2.getText().toString();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btn1:

            break;
        case R.id.txtsua:
           startActivity(new Intent(this,Setup.class));

    }
}
```

---

Setup class=> it place show text of button

```
 public class Setup extends Activity {

 Main1 main=new Main1();

String a1,b1;
EditText editText;
Spinner spinner;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    a1=main.getA();
    b1=main.getB();
    ArrayList<String> ar=new ArrayList<String>();
    ar.add(a1);
    ar.add(b1);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setup);
    editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed1);
    spinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arr=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,ar);
    arr.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
    spinner.setAdapter(arr);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_setup, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly, it's alsmost unreadable as you posted it now

Comment: if i do   " ar.add("a")...=> it work fine. i don't understand

Comment: Please format yout code

Comment: Not just format, but add what you want to find out. We can't look at your whole code and expect to know what you're looking for specifically.

Comment: You shouldn't be creating Activities with "new". It looks like you have little idea on how Android development is done, so I'd recommend reading some "getting started" material prior to writing any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the text buttons in intent when you are going to second activity.
And retrieve it into Setup Activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,Setup.class);
intent.putExtras("text1",button1.getText().toString());
intent.putExtras("text2",button2.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

and in Setup.class

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String text1 = intent.getStringExtra("text1");
String text2 = intent.getStringExtra("text2");
```

Comment: can u show the onCreate() method of your Setup activity after using my code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SharedPreferences` or `putExtra("key", "value")` in the intent.

**Method 1**

In `Main1` activity :

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

editor.putString("button1Text", button1.getText().toString());
//do this for all buttons
editor.commit();
```

And then in `Setup` activity,

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String button1Text = sharedPreferences.getString("button1Text");
//do this for all buttons
```

**Method 2**

In Main1 Activity :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Main1.this, Setup.class);
intent.putExtras("button1Text", button1.getText().toString());
//do this for all buttons
startActivity(intent);
```

In Setup Activity :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String button1Text = intent.getStringExtra("button1Text");
//do this for required buttons
```

If you use `SharedPreferences` you will be able to access the data in any other activity as well.

Comment: i'm try use Method 2,but it not work,i don't understand

Comment: Get rid of `Main1 main=new Main1();`
you dont need the main.getA() methods.

After `setContrentView()` 

write these lines

`Intent intent = getIntent();
String button1Text = intent.getStringExtra("button1Text");
//do this for required buttons`

and then create the `ArrayList` and add these Strings to the `ArrayList`.